# How to call jquery click method by specified element instead of $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a method like this;

```
 $('.kaldir').click(function () {
        var thisCheck = $(this);
        ..... 
  }
```

and my html input(s) like this;

```
<input type="radio" name="chbBesDiger" class="kaldir" id="chbBeslenme" value="Beslenme" />
```

this method is working well, but I need to run  `$('.kaldir').click()` method for just `chbBeslenme` input with jquery code,

I tried,

```
$("#chbBeslenme").click() 
           or 
$("#chbBeslenme .kaldir").click()
```

but it didn't work. How can i do that ?

Comment: `$("#chbBeslenme").click()` should work. Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: What is your requirement ???

Comment: `$("#chbBeslenme").click()` works for me: http://jsbin.com/IVuGEcA/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/IVuGEcA/1/edit))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#chbBeslenme").trigger('click');
```

OR

```
$("#chbBeslenme .kaldir").trigger('click');
```

Comment: `.click()` is shorthand for `.trigger("click")`. If `.click()` doesn't work, `.trigger("click")` won't.

Answer (score 0):

Use .trigger() http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
$( ".kaldir" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: `.click()` is shorthand for `.trigger("click")`. If `.click()` doesn't work, `.trigger("click")` won't.